# Python Gtk3, How can I insert a Response (Button) to MessageDialog?

Tags: python, gtk3

some times I need to insert new response (button) to `MessageDialog` but I don't know how I can do this. for example `msg_dialog.insert_response(Gtk.STOCK_OK, Gtk.ResponseType.OK, 2)`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are looking for is [Gtk.Dialog.add_button](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Dialog.html#Gtk.Dialog.add_button):

> Adds a button with the given text and sets things up so that clicking
>   the button will emit the Gtk.Dialog ::response signal with the given
>   response_id. The button is appended to the end of the dialog’s action
>   area. The button widget is returned, but usually you don’t need it.

If you want to add several buttons, then you can use [Gtk.Dialog.add_buttons](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Dialog.html#Gtk.Dialog.add_buttons):

> The add_buttons() method adds several buttons to the Gtk.Dialog using
>   the button data passed as arguments to the method. This method **is the
>   same as calling the Gtk.Dialog.add_button() repeatedly**.
>
> The button data pairs - button text (or stock ID) and a response ID integer are passed individually. For **example**:
>
> ```
> dialog.add_buttons(Gtk.STOCK_OPEN, 42, "Close", Gtk.ResponseType.CLOSE)
> ```
>
> will add “Open” and “Close” buttons to dialog.